# Javascript fake click which triggers affiliate pop-up is being blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

My page has an affiliate pop-up whenever someone clicks anywhere on the page. This part works fine.

So then I created a script where if they haven't clicked on their own after a while it will simulate a click, thus triggering the pop-up. However, the browser can somehow tell that this is a fake click & auto-blocks the pop-up (but it works fine if you actually click on the page, the browser won't block the pop-up then).

I've tried various ways of simulating a real-world click in javascript but nothing works. Any ideas of how to stop it from blocking the pop-up?

Comment: Can you post some code dude to express a better view of your problem?

Comment: While I don't personally like this kind of behavior why bother simulating a click?  Just do the pop-up in a setTimeout function and clearTimeout in your click function.

Comment: The ad people can tell if I'm just triggering the pop-up directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot a trigger false click event so that your popup is not blocked by the browser. This is a not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Popups will only work if they originate from a [trusted event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) that is an event that the user initiated. In your first case the user clicks on the page causing a trusted event which allows it to open. Your second case however the user has made no such action, so no trusted event and no popup.